# Sending thousands notifications on PHP (Symfony2) using SQS

Tags: php, performance, symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a Symfony2 app that under some circumstances has to send more than 10.000 push and email notifications.

I developed a SQS flow with some workers polling the queues to send emails and mobile push notifications.

But now, I have the problem that, when in the request/response cycle I need to send to SQS this task/jobs (maybe not that amount) this task itself is consuming a lot of time (response timeout is normally reached).

Should I process this task at background (I need to send back a quick response)? And how to handle possible errors with this scenario?

NOTE: Amazon SQS can receive 10 messages at one request and I already using this method. Maybe should I build a simple SQS Message with a lot of notifications jobs (max. 256K) to send less HTTP requests to SQS?

Answer (score 3):

The moment you have a single action that triggers 10k actions, you need to try to find a way to tell the user that "OK, I got it. I'll start working on it and will let you know when it's done".

So to bring that work into the background, a domain event should be raised from your user's action which would be queued into SQS. The user gets notified, and then a worker can pick up that message from the queue and start sending emails and push notifications to another queue.

At the end of the day, 10k messages in batches of 10 are just 1k requests to SQS, which should be pretty quick anyway.

Try to keep your messages small. Don't send the whole content of an email into a queue message, because then you'll get unnecessary long latencies. Keep the content in a reachable place or just query for it again when consuming the message instead of passing big content up and down the network.

Comment: Hi @hasumedic, thanks for your reply. I think that a queue to send jobs to another queue is a very good idea. Sure I will develop something like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> And how to handle possible errors with this scenario?

Amazon provides [dead letter queues](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/SQSDeadLetterQueue.html) for this.  In asynchronous systems I've built, I usually create a queue and then attach a redrive policy to it that says "if I see the same message on this queue 10 times, send it to a dead letter queue so that it doesn't bounce back and forth between the queue and a consumer for all eternity".  The dead letter queue is simply another queue.

From a dead letter queue you can decide what to do with data that did not process.  Since it's notifications (emails or push notifications) in your case, you might have another component in your system that will periodically reprocess a dead letter queue.  [Scheduled Lambdas](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html) are good for this.

Comment: Hi @kevin628, thanks for your answer. I'm already using scheduled lambdas to complete another tasks and I think I can use it in this scenario too. I will certainly find out about dead letter queues. Thanks.